# typeof gives me a number but console.log of the same variable gives me NAN how do i fix this

Tags: javascript

```js
store = {
  bags: {
    inventory: 30,
    cost: 12.99
  },
  pen: {
    inventory: 30,
    cost: 34.23
  }
};
const buy = (x, y) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if (x === "bags" && y >= 1 && y < 30) {
      resolve(parseInt(y * store.bags.cost));
    } else {
      reject("out of order");
    }
  });
};

const buy1 = (x, y) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if (x === "pen" && y >= 1 && y < 30) {
      resolve(parseInt(y * store.pen.cost));
    } else {
      reject("out of order");
    }
  });
};

const totalBag = [];
const totalPen = [];

parseInt(totalBag.push(buy("bags", 12)));
parseInt(totalPen.push(buy1("pen", 12)));

const total = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if (x === "pen" && y >= 1 && y < 30) {
      resolve(parseInt(y * store.pen.cost));
    } else {
      reject("out of order");
    }
  });
};

totalsum = 0;
totalsum = parseInt(totalBag) + parseInt(totalPen);

console.log(typeof totalsum);
console.log(totalsum);
```

Comment: In JS the type of `NaN` is number. Use `isNaN()` to detect NaN.

Comment: `totalBag` and `totalPen` are arrays. Why are you trying to `parseInt` them? Also, what is `parseInt(totalBag.push(buy('bags',12)))` supposed to do?

Comment: if you console.log(totalBag) you get 155, that should answer your question why I did that

Comment: @fabollang if you `console.log(totalBag)` then you get an array with a single Promise in it. The value *inside* the Promise *after* it's fulfilled is `155`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because `typeof NaN = number`, strange but true

Comment: It actually makes sense. You are using a function that will return a number, say, `parseInt`. You don't want it to throw an error, nor do you want it to return an actual value that is not a number like `null` or `undefined` - you only want numbers. So you need a numeric value that signifies a non-numeric value, e.g., doing `parseInt("apple")` will give you `NaN` because "apple" cannot be converted to an integer. Same with `parseInt("orange")`. This also explains why `NaN != NaN` - after all `"apple" != "orange"`.

Comment: I agree with your reasoning, I'm not trying to imply it's wrong by the way, I'm in no position to say that. But at first glance it honestly feels strange to say the typeof not-a-number is number, at least to me. However, your examples and explanation makes it pretty clear why it's needed.

Comment: thanks for the reply, but when I remove the promise it worked as expected which doesn't make sense to me anymore.

Answer (score 0):

**

### Thanks a lot for all your comments, I finally figured it out

** 
store = {

```
bags : { 
    inventory : 30,

    cost : 12.99

},

pen : {

   inventory : 30,

   cost : 34.23
}
```

};

const totalBag = [ ];

const totalPen = [ ];

const buy = (x,y,)=>{

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{

    if(x ==='bags'  && y >= 1 && y< 30 ){

        resolve(totalBag.push(parseInt((y*store.bags.cost))));

    }else { reject ('out of order');}; 

});
```

};
const buy1 = (x1,y1)=>{

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{

    if(x1 ==='pen'  && y1 >= 1 && y1< 30 ){

        resolve(totalPen.push((parseInt((y1*store.pen.cost)))));

    }else { reject ('out of order');}; 

});
```

};

const amtBag = buy('bags',10);

const amtPen = buy1('pen',10);

let tbag = Number(totalBag);

let tpen = Number(totalPen);

let TotalPurchase = console.log(tbag + tpen);